# Allow user to delete own account - Authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make it such that a user can delete their own account.

```
def destroy
 @user = current_user
 @user.destroy
 redirect_to root_url
end
```

But it looks like authlogic will not allow the current_user to delete their own account.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
current_user_session.user.destroy
```

instead

Comment: No luck.  It is still requiring authentication.